# JPA: If else Case not working on Query

Tags: java, jpa, return, repository

In the following code I want to return true or false when data is found but it gives me following error :| I want to return true or false when record which have specific email and also its group id is true

```
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("Select User (CASE WHEN count(u) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) from User u where u.email = :email and u.group.id=2")
      boolean findGroupOfUser(@Param("email") String email);
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'User' {originalText=User}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[CASE] SearchedCaseNode: 'CASE'
          +-[WHEN] SqlNode: 'WHEN'
          |  +-[GT] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '>'
          |  |  +-[COUNT] CountNode: 'count'
          |  |  |  \-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'user0_.id' {alias=u, className=com.ivl.townsmate.model.User, tableAlias=user0_}
          |  |  \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '0'
          |  \-[TRUE] BooleanLiteralNode: 'TRUE'
          \-[ELSE] SqlNode: 'ELSE'
             \-[FALSE] BooleanLiteralNode: 'FALSE'

    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
```

Comment: `Select User from User u...`??? I'd bet that should be `Select u from User u...` instead. Additionally, it should probably be `Select u, (case ... ) from User u ...` (note the comma). Finally I'd assume that `count(u)` isn't going to work correctly if you're selecting from `u`, i.e. if it works at all (normally you'd either only select aggregate data or count on groups) you'd probably always get 1.

Comment: I modified my query as 
`@Query("Select u from User u where u.email = :email and u.group.id=2 AND (CASE WHEN count(u) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) ")`

Now it gives me an error : unexpected AST node: CASE near line 1 @Thomas

Comment: As I said, that `count(u)` doesn't quite work. What should that accomplish?

Comment: Tell me how can I return true or false when data is found or not? @Thomas

Comment: Ah, I overlooked "I want to return true or false when record which have specific email and also its group id is true" - if I understand you correctly you want to get _all_ users and a flag whether they match or not, is that so? In that case using the where clause as you did is the from way. Do you _really_ want to get all non-matching users?

Comment: `@Query("Select u from User u where u.group.id= 2 and u.email= :email")
 Boolean findGroup(@Param ("email") String email);`

Like This? @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to check whether *any* users with the given email and groupid 2 exist your query should more look like this:

```
select count(u) > 0 from User u where u.email = :email and u.group.id=2
```

If you want to get all users that match the query should look like this:

```
select u from User u where u.email = :email and u.group.id=2
```

If you want to get all users along with a flag whether they match or not the query would be something like this:

```
select u, u.email = :email and u.group.id=2 from User u
```